# Number of Pure Strategies in a 3-card Goofspiel game

Tags: combinatorics

I am unable to work out the number of pure strategies in a 3-card Goofspiel game. I believe the general formula for it is $n^n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{k(k+1)}$ for n-card Goofspiel. But I get the answer to be $(3!)^3$ as this is the number of different permutations of game play.

The 3-card Goofspiel (2-player) game works as follows: Two players A and B are dealt 3 'bid' cards with the numbers 1,2 and 3. A separate dealer deals 3 'black' cards face up, one at a time, in a random order. The black cards are also labelled 1, 2 and 3. After each black card is dealt, both players make a bid using their bid cards simultaneously and the player that plays a higher bid card wins that black card. After all 3 black cards are dealt (after 3 rounds of bidding), the winner is the player that has the larger sum of the black cards. If the sum is the same, the game ends in a tie. If both players bid the same bid card, then no one gets the black card for that round. Once a bid card is used, you cannot use the same bid card again.

Comment: A single strategy should cover all possible permutations of gameplay.

Comment: One might hypothetically imagine that not everyone who could answer your question knows what a "3-card Goofspiel game" is.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I tend to agree. Is it more like 3-Card Monte of Left-Handed Fizzbin?

Comment: @MishaLavrov just explained the game in the question

Answer (score 1):

A strategy must specify the first bid card you play (based only on the first card dealt) and the second bid card you play (based on the first two cards dealt and on the opponent's first bid).

In other words, to describe a strategy, we must fill in the blanks below:

- If the first card is a 1, play ___. Then:

  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.
- If the first card is a 2, play ___. Then:

  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 3 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.
- If the first card is a 3, play ___. Then:

  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 1 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 1 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 2 on the first round, play ___.
  - If the second card is a 2 and the opponent played 3 on the first round, play ___.

(There is no need to specify the third card played, since there are no choices to be made.)

For each of the "If the first card is X, play ___" blanks, there are $3$ options. For each of the other $18$ blanks, there are $2$ options, because the second play must be different from the first. Altogether, there are $3^3 \cdot 2^{18}$ ways to fill in the blanks.

The reason we get a different answer from $(3!)^3 = 3^3 \cdot 2^3$ is that the second play of the game is based on more information than the first; therefore, there are more different scenarios in which a strategy needs to describe its second play. (More precisely, there are $18$ different scenarios, depending on the first two bid cards drawn and the first card played by the opponent.)

The general formula is also incorrect. It should be $$\prod_{k=1}^n k^{n!/(n-k)! \cdot n!/(n-k-1)!}.$$ The exponent on $k$ is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!}$, the number of possibilities for the cards you've seen dealt and played by the time you are playing a card with $k$ options remaining.